# Curved vector graphics using paths

Tags: r, graphics

When drawing curved shapes in R, they are typically made up of a collection of short straight line segments (with circular line endings). The result looks good to the human eye but is a bit of a roundabout way of doing it as you need to interpolate the curve to get the coordinates of the segments. It also produces unnecessarily large files, although this is not a big problem unless the plot contains an extreme amount of curves.

Is there a way to create curved vector shapes the proper way using paths made up of anchor and pivot points as in the figure below?

[image]

Comment: What figure? (apologies if it's my local IT blocking the image).  Anyway, have you looked at the package `plotrix` ? It may have some useful tricks.  There's also the function `curve` which will plot any function you can define.

Comment: The `grid` package has `bezierGrob`, `bezierPoints`, `grid.bezier` ...

Comment: Thanks a lot! "Bezier" was the magic word I didn't find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: "No".

Long answer: R doesn't know if your output device supports describing curves from formulae - for example PDF and PostScript can (I think) have arcs and curves, but R doesn't know if its drawing to one of those or to a bitmap device.

Hence when you want to draw an arc on an R plot, it can't do:

```
0 0 moveto
25 25 pi arcto
```

(or whatever the PostScript is) to describe an arc that will be infinitely smoothly zoomable. It has to render the arc into segments.

If you run the example in `help(bezierGrob)` to a PDF device and zoom in, you can see the segments (zoomed in to 500%).

Comment: this is an interesting question, though -- which aspects of R graphics are handled in this "least-common-denominator" style and which (e.g. alpha transparency, rasters, ...) are more flexible?  Could they be made more flexible?

Comment: Check out the definition of graphics devices in the C code of grDevices - lots of `dev->polyline = FOO_Polyline` lines for each device's rendering function. There's a '->circle' method but no arc or curve. It would mean adding a method there, and implementing it via line segments for devices with no native support.

Comment: Interesting... That is beyond what I can justify spending working hours on, so I'll stick to the segmented version, but the fact that I can express the curves as beziers greatly helps me draw them. Btw, do you know if there is a function for drawing filled bezier shapes? I can't find any.